# Wordpress - footer.php not loading

Tags: wordpress, footer

I've tried numerous searches and haven't had any luck finding a solution. I'm currently trying to get my footer.php to call correctly from my index.php file, but nothing I seem to do fixes it. I'm trying to launch it tonight for a client to see in the morning and when tying up the last bit of code, this problem arose.

Here's the code I'm using to call the footer.php from my index.php file:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here's the footer code at the moment (just for testing):

```
Testing footer.
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And on a side note, in case it makes a difference, I have wordpress installed in a subdirectory, "wordpress", and I'm using the .htaccess file to redirect the domain to that directory. Here's the code for my .htaccess file (replaced domain with "DOMAINNAME"):

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?DOMAINNAME.org$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress [L]
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using htaccess rules for your redirect, this may resolve your footer issue [Installing WordPress with Security In Mind](http://tentblogger.com/installing-wordpress/)

Comment: I actually disabled the .htaccess redirect completely and went to the /wordpress/ directory to view the site and it didn't fix the problem.  Is there any other files that might be affecting it?  I don't mind posting the code from them.  I'm just all of out of ideas.

Thanks for trying to help, Bc.

Comment: What is your WordPress URL value set to?  The sub folder or the domain name?  (Settings > General)